# Why is this oscillator's output gets distorted?

Tags: oscillator

The following oscillator is outputting distorted sine waves during the end of negative swings:

[image]

What could be the reason? How to fix this issue? I tried to play with some parameters like C1, C2, L and Vs or even R1 and R2, but I couldn't succeed anything.

Comment: Better question: Why do you think they should be? Telling us your reasoning might be useful to pinpoint the mistake in the reasoning.

Comment: CLUE: You have negative voltages on the output... what might that do to a 2N2222 with it's emitter hooked indirectly to ground?

Comment: For now I can say that the voltage at the base causing this.

Comment: @Trevor This is a Colpitt's topology taken from here: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/osc55.gif I also dont get how without a negative rail this provides negative voltage up to -9V.. Capacitor makes that but why distorted

Comment: By the magic of that curly thing above the transistor. Regardless, it is obvious from the trace something is not liking the voltage going that low... only active part is Q1.. check the data sheet and figure out which parameter you are exceeding. I'd tell you, but then you would not learn much.

Comment: It look like the transistor goes to saturation after some point Vce becomes zero

Comment: *Capacitor makes that* What capacitor? C4 ? It cannot even charge or discharge as nothing is connected on its right side. You can leave C4 out as it does nothing until you connect something there. The inductor L2 is very much involved as well in making the negative voltage.

Comment: Hint: an oscillators output grows until something (nonlinearity) limits it. So the real question is how can you design an oscillator without distortion.

Comment: Yes C4 blocks the DC if coupled to a resistor

Comment: One method to avoid output distortion is to absorb energy proportional to V^2. And a resistor somewhere in the path of the circulating energy will do that. If you restrict the total energy available, by using a constant current amplifier, such as a differential pair, then the V^2 or I^2 approach will succeed.

Comment: @Trevor Which parameter exceeding? I checked abs max ratings

Comment: @user16307 which voltage under electrical characteristics is less than 10V